# How to call function once in testcases in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

If i execute below testcase i get the below output

sample

test_a

sample

test_b

In this function sample() executes every method in testcases , i want to execute function at the start of the testcase not every method . I want out put like below

sample

test_a

test_b

Ex:

```
def sample():

    print("sample")

class Test_example(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        sample()

    def test_a(self):
        print("test_a")

    def test_b(self):
        print("test_b")
```

Comment: "Above testcase"  ???

Answer (score 0):

You want a class scoped fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def sample():
    print("sample")
```

But you need to explicitly use the fixture in your tests:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("sample")
class Test_example(APITestCase):
    def test_x(self):
        pass
```

Note that you don't need to call the fixture, either. It's a feature of your testing suite and is automatically called by pytest.

Comment: if i execute i got  "TypeError: test_x() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" erros

Comment: Let me know if it's still broken (I'm on a phone so haven't tested).